# Sitecore WFFM error Unknown connection string. Name: 'wfm'

Tags: sitecore

I am new in Sitecore, i have created form using WFFM and i want to save form in sqlServer, so i have installed SaveToDatabase from [here](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Web_Forms_for_Marketers_SQL_SaveToDatabase.aspx), trying to save from in database but it is giving error:

**4184 20:12:45 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
4184 20:12:46 ERROR Save To Database failed.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Unknown connection string. Name: 'wfm'
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetConnectionString(String connectionStringName)
   at WFFM.SQLServer.SaveToDatabase.Model.FormRepository.Insert(ID formId, AdaptedResultList fields, ID sessionID, String data)
   at WFFM.SQLServer.SaveToDatabase.Infrastructure.Actions.SaveToDatabase.Execute(ID formId, AdaptedResultList fields, Object[] data)**

Please help me or suggest me how can i save WFFM form in sqlServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a connection string to your connectionstrings.config with the name wfm. This will point to your web forms database and allow you to use SQL server.

```xml
 <add name="WFM" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="user id=xx;password=xx;Data Source=xx;Database=WebFormsdb" />
```

The module you mentioned relies on you setting up the database as you would prior to Sitecore 7.5.

To set this database up you should attach the mdf and ldf file to a SQL server instance.

These files can be found with the download of Wffm. When you have finished the install of wffm there will be a data folder in your web root - the database files are in there.

If you are have installed wffm 2.5 the database may not be available in the package as MongoDb is intended to be used. So you might have to get it from a previous version. Simply download an older version of wffm and extract the files from the package.

Comment: I am using Sitecore 8 so i have installed WFFM 8.0 and SaveToDatabse 2.5. I have attached Sitecore_analytics,Sitecore_core,Sitecore_master,Sitecore_sessions,Sitecore_web these five database and there was also a one database script WFFM_Analytics in data folder when i installed WFFM 8.0 but i am not able to find WebFormsdb database which you have mentioned above. Please guide me if i am wrong.

Comment: If you want to use the old style web forms SQL database rather than the default Mongo db, download the package for an older version of web forms for marketers, open up the package zip file - look in the files folder /data the database files will be there.